# how to place form in layout in firemonkey android

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

I Am trying to place a form inside a `tlayout` in firemonkey android platform  but when i try to create a parent form in firemonkey its shows as full screen ?

as example i do something like this

```
Form2 := Tform2.create(nil);
form2.parent := layout1
form2.visible := True;
```

but the form shows as fullscreen not inside the `Tlayout` i try to do `form2.fullscreen := False;` but nothing changes  the form shows in full screen . how to place a form into a layout in firemonkey android platform ?

Comment: You can't put a form into a layout. Check out Firemonkey "Frames", that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible do that in FireMonkey like VCL. You can do a workaround, create a Layout inside of your form2, set the align to Client, put all controls there instead of put directly in the form.

```
Form2 := Tform2.create(nil);
Form2.mainLayout.parent := layout1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TFrame.

If you need to show a form on mobile OS NOT on full screen: 
Check form transparent checkbox - and place on form TLayout with HorizontalCenter Align, on this layout place second Layout with VerticalCenter Align. Then Place on this layout controls you need.